# Unable to Show LUB Property for Reals using Construction from Cauchy Sequences of Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I seem to run into circles when I proceed in these steps.

Step 1: Show there exists an equivalence relation on set of all Cauchy sequences of rational numbers and define the real numbers as the quotient induced by this relation.

Step 2: Show there exists a well-defined addition and multiplication on the set defined in step 1 and then show this set is a field.

Step 3: Show there exists a well-defined total order relation on the set defined in step 1 and then show the result of step 2 is an ordered ring.

In the next step, I want to show the ordered ring from step 3 has the least upper bound property, and this is where I experience a serious derailment.

In both books I am using, the least upper bound property is assumed. In many resources I find online, the least upper bound property is explicitly or implicitly treated as an axiomatic property of the real numbers. Most proofs I find online assume the least upper bound property holds for reals. Not directly, but usually with a few hops. For example, the proof at

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property][1]

starts with, "It is possible to prove the least-upper-bound property using the assumption that every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges." Unfortunately, I seem to need the least upper bound property to show "every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges."

I have one utube posting that seems to prove the least upper bound property but it relies on Dedekind cuts and these are not in my zoo of knowledge at this time.

My question then is: is it possible to show the least upper property holds for real numbers using the steps I am trying?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes.  Assume your sequence of reals is monotone (by taking a subsequence if necessary).  Recall that each element of your Cauchy sequence is itself an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences.  Choose a specific representative of each sequence and work with the sequence of sequences.  You should be able to construct a (sort of) diagonal subsequence that is Cauchy and that is the limit of your sequence of reals.  That completes the proof.

Comment: For this approach, I believe I need to show "A sequence of real numbers converges if and only if the sequence is Cauchy." And that needs after several back hops, the least upper bound property established.

Comment: I don't think so.  The new sequence you are creating is a Cauchy sequence (of rationals), so it is itself a (representative of) a real number.  All you need to prove is that the given Cauchy sequence (of reals) converges to real number represented by the Cauchy sequence (of rationals) that you've constructed.

Comment: OK, interesting. Thanks for your 2nd reply. I shall look into it further. Thank you!

Comment: After some thought and further research, I believe the best way to continue is to learn Dedekind cuts. Thanks again